# How to setup user webhook subscription for Calendly?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webhooks, calendly

I have read the [docs](https://help.calendly.com/hc/en-us/articles/223195488-Getting-started-with-webhooks) for Calendly, but it seems incomplete and I coulnd't know exactly how to set it up. I don't know where to start..As far as I know, I need to use OAuth2 and setup a user webhook subscription (correct me if I am wrong). If I am already using Clerk, do I still need to setup OAuth2?

**Problem:**
I want to fetch Calendly events to my React/NextJS app whenever someone books an appointment, so I can notify both the host and the invitee through their accounts on my website. Google Calendar and Gmail do this, but I am required to notify users on our website as well (junior developer here).

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0Vsl.png)

**Question:**
Can I ask how can I specifically set user webhook subscriptions? If there better ways to notify users on my site, please do tell me, too :)) There are only few YouTube video/articles about this, so I went to stackoverflow. Thank you!